# Item counts and sizes within a folder structure

Tags: powershell-3.0

Counting and measuring folder content

Trying to script check for large folders in within a directory structure.

My test script only seem to work accurately on top level folder and only with two separate Get-ChildItem commands, one to provide count the other the sum.

```bsh
$profiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users"

ForEach ($user in $profiles) {

<# getting the total number of items in the folder first #>
$itemsInfo1 = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$user" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$allitemsCount = $itemsInfo1.Count

<# getting the total size of all items in the folder second #>
$itemsInfo2 = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$user" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$allitemsSize = $itemsInfo2.Sum

$itemsSizeMB = [System.Math]::Round((($allitemsSize)/1MB),2) 
$itemsSizeGB = [System.Math]::Round((($allitemsSize)/1GB),2) 

Write-Host $user,$allitemsCount" Items",$itemsSizeMB" MB", $itemsSizeGB" GB"
```

I wanted to peruse this script on any folder by simple manual overwriting of the path in $profiles and $itemsInfo variables.

However changing the relevant paths by one level lower subfolder (e.g. $profiles = C:\Users\John) to see list of subfolders from there returns sum sizes as 0, count works ok.

Also contrary to my expectation the scrip only seems to return correct values when I use two separate Get-ChildItem commands as the .Sum and .Count properties returned by the two Get-ChildItem differ.

First Get-ChildItem (i.e. $itemsInfo1) seems to return correct count of items in the folder but incorrect sum of the sizes.
Second Get-ChildItem (i.e. $itemsInfo2) seems to return incorrect count of items (only counts files not folders?) in the folder but correct(er) sum of the sizes.

I used the GUI > folder properties to establish what a "correct" count and size should be.

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect counting issue relates to missing out hidden files. I.e. first Get-ChildItem cmdlet did not include `-Force`.

Changing the first line to `$profiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Force` resolved the issue for me.

To get the count of all items count and then sum of all items with "length" two separate (one for each variable) Get-ChildItem cmdlets are required as each only counts unique exact matches for stated properties.